# How to read a json file which contains an array from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Please guys help me because i can't find out what i can do in order to read my javascript a json file which contains an array with one element.

**My php file is working fine** and the output is a .json file which contains this line: `{"posts":[["30"]]}`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "mysql3");
// Check connection
if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user_id =$_POST['user_id'];
$book_id =$_POST['book_id'];
$game_id =$_POST['game_id'];
$site_id =$_POST['site_id'];

$sql= "SELECT site_id FROM components WHERE user_id='$user_id' && book_id='$book_id' && game_id='$game_id' ORDER BY site_id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$response = array();
$posts = array();
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $site_id=$row['site_id'];
  $posts[] = array($site_id);
} 
$response['posts'] = $posts;
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Can anybody help me what i have to do (without using ajax) in order my javascript function reads that value? I want to rerad this value cause i want to manipulate this number.

```
    function load3() {
          var flag1 = true;
          do{
            var selection = window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!");
                if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection)) {
                flag1=false;
                }
            }
            while(flag1!=false);
                $("#user_id").val(selection)

                var flag2 = true;
            do{
                var selection2 = window.prompt("Give the Book Id:", "Type a number!");
                if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection2)) {
                   flag2=false;
                }
            }
            while(flag2!=false);
                $("#book_id").val(selection2)

                var flag3= true;
            do{
                var selection3 = window.prompt("Give the Game Id:", "Type a number!");
                if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection3)) {
                    flag3=false;
                }
            }
            while(flag3!=false);
                $("#game_id").val(selection3)

               //i do not want to do with ajax!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!            
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'http://127.0.0.1/PHP/loo.php',
                   data: $('#LoadGame').serialize(),
                   success: function (html) {
                      //do something on success?
                      $('#outPut').html(html);
                      var bingoValue=4;
                      if( $('#outPut').text().indexOf(''+bingoValue) > 0){
                         //alert('bingo!');
                         window.location.href='https://support.wwf.org.uk/';

               //document.location.replace('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload');
                     }
                     else {
                        alert('No!');
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: on ajax success you are getting a json response isn't?

Comment: `results.json` is created on the server. To read it on a page using JS you *need* ajax. To grab the `30`, do `$.getJSON('results.json', r => { num = parseInt(r.posts[0][0]); alert(num) });`

Comment: @ChrisG nice. Where i have to put this line? In my JS function, right? because it doesn't show me an alert and secondly it drives me to my php file..

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes. but can i make with another way the comunication between javascript and php file (which is on the server side) without ajax?

Comment: @ChrisG i found something. look this:https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/ and go to jquery. it says that that can be done without ajax...

Comment: I edited the tag since this is about PHP and how to use that given your "not ajax" related comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this PHP code runs during your doc request,

You can read that json if you put it in a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myJson = <?php echo(json_encode($response)); ?>
</script
```

and it will be accessible as window.myJson in frontend

Comment: thanks for the advice. if you don't mind can you tell me where i hiave to put these lines of code in order to test it?

Comment: I have edited the post, you can put it after 
```mysqli_close($link);
?>```

Comment: unfortunately it says error. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp64\www\PHP\loo.php on line 33` i believe that the syntax is wrong. how we write script inside php?

Comment: I just saw `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>` in the start of your code

Comment: yes but i think that we sould echo your code with quotes..what do you say?

Comment: not if you put it after `?>`
You can try though whatever suits you better